# ¿Cómo puedo alinear mis div dentro de columnas para que los textos que contienen se vean adyacentes?

Tags: html, css

Pregunta tonta, pero realmente no logro alinearlos.
tengo dos columnas, cada una tiene un `div` dentro, el segundo `div` no se alinea con el texto del primer:
[image: mi footer]

¿Cómo puedo alinear mis `div` con CSS?

```css
footer{
    height: 260px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}
#contacto{
    color: #777777;
}
#end{
    padding: 60px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    width: 640px;
}
.column2{
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="column2" id="end">
        <div>
            <h4 id="contacto">CONTACTO</h4>
            <p class="leftend">Telefono:</p>
            <p class="leftend">Email:</p>
            <p class="leftend">Direccion:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightend">
            <p class="rightend">4023-5210</p>
            <p class="rightend">panda@pandaong.org</p>
            <p class="rightend">B1904 La Plata, Provincia de Buenos Aires</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: yo en tu caso usaría flex para así también poder hacerlo responsiv

Comment: Hola, espero que te sirva mi respuesta. La pregunta no es tonta, alinear elementos ha sido un problema desde los albores del diseño web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
footer{
    height: 260px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}
#contacto{
    color: #777777;
}
.column2 {
    padding: 60px;
    color: #eeeeee;


    display: flex;
    /* posiciona verticalmente las cajas */
    align-items: flex-end;
    /* posiciona horizontalmente las cajas */
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="column2" id="end">
        <div>
            <h4 id="contacto">CONTACTO</h4>
            <p class="leftend">Telefono:</p>
            <p class="leftend">Email:</p>
            <p class="leftend">Direccion:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightend">
            <p class="rightend">4023-5210</p>
            <p class="rightend">panda@pandaong.org</p>
            <p class="rightend">B1904 La Plata, Provincia de Buenos Aires</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Primero, yo no usaría identificadores para aplicar estilos, no es una buena práctica. En cuanto a la solución que propuse: he usado **flex-box**.

El `display: flex`, se aplica a un contenedor y afecta al posicionamiento de los elementos internos, se pueden ajustar verticalmente con `align-items` y horizontalmente con `justify-content`.

Las cajas dentro del *contendor flex* aparecerán siempre centradas horizontalmente gracias a `justify-content:center`, no es necesario que el contenedor tenga un ancho asignado. Para separar el texto de ambas "columnas" puedes aplicar un margen de separación a una de ellas, por ejemplo, un `margin-right:3rem;` a la primera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta solución NO modifica el HTML preexistente, pero tiene un problema: si reduces el ancho de pantalla cuando el tengo de una de la segunda caja ya no cabe, pasa a la siguiente línea y los textos dejan de estar alineados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes la opción de modificar la estructura del HTML puedes poner el encabezado contacto fuera de la primera caja de texto, y aplicar otros estilos:

```css
  footer{
      height: 260px;
      background-color: #333333;
      border-top-right-radius: 100px;
      border-top-left-radius: 100px;

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  footer h4 {
      color: #777777;
  }

  .column2 {
      padding: 60px;
      color: #eeeeee;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: baseline;
  }
  .two-cols {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="column2" id="end">
        <h4 id="contacto">CONTACTO</h4>
        <div class="two-cols">
            <div style="margin-right: 3rem;">
                <p class="leftend">Telefono:</p>
                <p class="leftend">Email:</p>
                <p class="leftend">Direccion:</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="rightend">4023-5210</p>
                <p class="rightend">panda@pandaong.org</p>
                <p class="rightend">B1904 La Plata, Provincia de Buenos Aires</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Es un poco más complicado, pero si se reduce el ancho de pantalla no se rompe la alineación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]